# jQuery this and Selector $(this:first-child).css('color', 'red');

Tags: jquery, selector, this

Is it possible to use a `:selector` with the following in jQuery?

```
$('.galler_attr').bind('click', function() {
   $(this:first-child).css('color', 'red'); 
      });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for the first child of the clicked element or want to check if the clicked element is the first child of its parent. Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. You're trying to mix the function context with a string.

Use `this` as the **[context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)** of the selector or call `find()` on `$(this)` to search within the DOM scope of the element. Either

```
$('.galler_attr').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).find(':first-child').css('color', 'red'); 
});
```

or this (which resolves to the above internally):

```
$('.galler_attr').bind('click', function() {
   $(':first-child', this).css('color', 'red'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it but not in such a way. You can put it as Russ says.

```
$('.galler_attr').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).find(':first-child').css('color', 'red'); 
});
```

You can get better help for such problems by going to www.visualjquery.com. It's pretty.

Answer (score 0):

in that case, use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$('.galler_attr').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).is(':first-child').css('color', 'red');
   // this would change the color to red if the clicked element is a first-child....
});
```

I wonder why not just bind it to the first-child directly?

```
$('.galler_attr:first-child').bind('click', function() {
   // this would bind click event to the first-child element...
   $(this).css('color', 'red');

});
```